# Find Periodic records in the dataframe in Python

Tags: python

ID represents an entity,Date on which transactions have occurred in USD.

I want to check for each ID that if the transaction have occurred in the periodic manner. if yes then what is the periodicity? 15 days, 20 days, 45 days...etc
(+- 10 variation of periodicity  in time delta)

Another complexity is that if the transaction also have some addition random transaction then how will i identify the periodicity?

i want to avoid the loops as it is taking too long if records are in millions.

please check the image for data

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL2Zs.jpg
```

Below is the Code i have created. I have checked only for last few records.

And its taking too.

```
store_df=[]
for idr in df['ID'].unique():
   inside_df=df[df['ID']==idr]
   inside_df['day_before']= inside_df['date'].shift(1)
   inside_df=inside_df.fillna(method='bfill')
   inside_df['days_difference']=inside_df['date']-inside_df['day_before']
   inside_df['days_difference']=inside_df['days_difference'].apply(lambda x:x.days)
   store_df.append(inside_df)
   #print(idr)
store_df=pd.concat(store_df)
store_df.head()



limit=0.1
count=0
obj = {}
ID_list=[]
diff_days_list=[]

for i in range(2, 100):
    obj['l'+'_'+str(i)] = []
    for idr in store_dfr['ID'].unique()[0:]:    
        temp_df=store_dfr[store_dfr['ID']==idr]
        #temp_df=temp_df
        if (i*(1-limit))<temp_df['days_difference'].iloc[-1]<(i*(1+limit)):
            if (i*(1-limit))<temp_df['days_difference'].iloc[-2]<(i*(1+limit)):
                if ((i*(1-limit))<temp_df['days_difference'].iloc[-3]<(i*(1+limit))) or ((2*i*(1-limit))<temp_df['days_difference'].iloc[-3]<(2*i*(1+limit))):
                    obj['l'+'_'+str(i)].append(temp_df)
                    count=count+1
                    ID_list.append(idr)
                    diff_days_list.append(i)
        else:
            del temp_df        
print(count)
list(ID_list)
list(diff_days_list)
```

The above code only checking for last few records for every ID. And also does not care of random transactions.

Comment: please include code, inputs, outputs, and expected outputs on a small test data sample

Answer (score 0):

Taking 2 parts to this:

First portion is to create the difference between rows:

```
#Assuming the data is in dataframe df

df2 = df
df2.sort(['ID', 'Date'], inplace=True)
df2['diffs'] = df2.groupby(['ID'])['Date'].transform(lambda x: x.diff())
```

Second portion is to find the mode difference for the same ID (effectively ignoring the stated issue of potential random transaction, provided that the random transactions are not too frequent  [eg 1 transaction between every periodic transaction])

```
d2f = (df2.groupby('ID', as_index=False)
        .agg({'diffs': lambda x: x.mode()}))
```